# How to select certain options from an alert in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, alerts

I have a macro that calls a number of other macros which work fine, but I would like to make it more automated - at the moment it requires users to click 'Yes' or 'No' or other similar options as the macro runs.

A sample is below:

```
Sheets("Macro").Select
Sheets("Hidden").Visible = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

intList = MsgBox("HerpDerp?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

If intList = vbNo Then Exit Sub

If (Range("asd").Value = "sdf" Or Range("asd").Value = "dfg") Then

othermacro1
othermacro2

Else

othermacro3
othermacro4

End If

Sheets("Macro").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets("Hidden").Visible = False

MsgBox "DerpHerp", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Save"

End Sub
```

Through troubleshooting I would have thought that setting alerts to automatically not display this would circumvent the problem, but users need to click more divers buttons than 'yes' or 'no' in order to continue with the macro, which may be why this is occurring (though I would have anticipated that this would just make the alert not appear...).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and any additional info required can easily be supplied.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code and hope this helps you:

Source Code:

```
Sub MsgBoxDemo()
    Dim Answer As Long

     Answer = MsgBox("Select Yes or No", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Reply")

      If Answer = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Yes"
      End If
      If Answer = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "No"
      End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of using msgboxes in the way so thanks for that, but it doesn't actually answer the question I asked. To clarify: I'd like to know what lines of code I could add to my macro that would allow users who run it to not have to answer alerts. "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" doesn't seem to do what I want in this case.

Comment: You have added Application.DisplayAlerts = True. Check your code.

Comment: Hi Paresh, thanks for your help so far. In the code I have added Application.DisplayAlerts = True after all of the macros have finished running (the only things that come after it are a message box explaining to the user that the macros have finished running). Is there something else I'm missing?